# getting unexpected result from the following statement

Tags: java, android

```
option1.setText(""+(answer+(rand.nextInt(10))))
```

I thought this will generate a number, a little bigger than 'answer'. But I'm getting very large difference. Is this statement correct?

Comment: What is the exact result (or at least give us a range), and what is the result you are seeing?. How large is the difference exactly? Also, what is 'answer' in this case?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might need to specify what you mean by "a little bigger" (e.g. do you mean 0 - 10 ?) and "very large difference" before anyone can help.

Comment: Try removing the parantheses around rand.nextInt(10).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 option1.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(answer)+rand.nextInt(10)));
```

is the correct way. `answer` is a string, and string + number results in a string concatenation and, therefore, the new value will be at least ten times the value of answer.

Converting the string `answer` to integer will make `+` behave as an arithmetic operator.

Answer (score 0):

It is very confusing to set a string with variables and doing calculations within a string. I've found the problem. sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Please use comments for this kind of communication.